# Sketch effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Anyone know how to make this kind of text effect in Photoshop? That pencil sketch effect...
[image]

Btw, I took this image from ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Comment: Definitely not programming related...

Comment: Fun thing to try in PS CS5: Remove Beta, select the white area around Ubuntu and inside the b letter, Select -> Fill -> Content-Aware Fill. I have no clue if you are allowed to use the original one though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to just use the same font...

http://www.dafont.com/sketch-block.font

Answer (score 1):

It's either 1) just a font that has this texture already OR 2) it's a regular font with a pattern overlay.

If you go to the blending properties of the text layer, there's an option to fill with pattern, "Pattern Overlay". Also, there's probably a 1px stroke that has the same or a slightly lighter colour as the pattern color.

[image: Screen shot]